# 'retract' functionaliy in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, post, get, crud

I have read how to add **extra member route** using **retract**, but couldn't understand it thoroughly. It is said that just like **edit** being a portal for **update**, **retract** is a portal for **destroy** where I am really thorough with CRUD functionalities. So Can I have a detailed, but a simple explanation how **retract** method works in **rails 3** with an example.

You can find the context here. [informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1671632&seqNum=8](http://informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1671632&seqNum=8)

Comment: where have you read this ?

Comment: @Baldrick: You can find the context here http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1671632&seqNum=8. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `retract` method in Rails. It is a route added to the controller of the resource as an example (it could have been named differently). This new action is added to the 7 default ones for resources: `index`, `new`, `create`, `show`, `edit`, `update`, `destroy`

You can look at the [Rails Routing Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) for more information on routing and resources, and particularly the chapter 2.9 that covers the same topic as your link.

Comment: I know the CRUD functionalities. I hope that retract is just similar to show, but named differently. Right? Thank you for your reply.

Comment: @Rajesh exactly; the `show` route call the `show` method in the controller and display the `show.htm.erb` view (if no `render` is called); the added `retract` route will call the `rectract` action in the controller and display the `retract.htm.erb` view (if no `render` is called).